# Distances on lattices with periodic boundaries

Tags: math, language-agnostic, distance

I have a square lattice, of size `LxL` . In this lattice, I can have the classical 4-neighbours grid or an 8-neighbour lattice (including also the diagonals).

Given the coordinates of two points on the lattice `(i1,j1)` and `(i2,j2)`, I want to compute the distance between them in the 4-neighbour grid and the 8-neighbour grid, considering also periodic boundary conditions.

For the 4-neighbour case, without periodic boundary conditions, the distance is the Manhattan distance `d=|i1-i2|+|j1-j2|`.
If I want to take in account the periodic boundaries, I could compute the distance several times (changing, for example, `(i2,j2)` by `(i2,j2-L)`) and take the minimum, but I am sure that there is a more efficient way to do this.

About the 8-neighbour case, I found this question: [Calculate distance on a grid between 2 points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368632/calculate-distance-on-a-grid-between-2-points) (in my case, I would replace `sqrt(2)` by 1) but it does not solve the problem with boundary conditions.

Any pseudocode on how to compute these distances? The faster, the better.

Comment: Probably not optimal, but you should be able to get modify the linked answer to reflect boundary conditions: It says  "move diagonally towards the goal until you're either on the same row or same col". With boundary conditions all 4 possible diagonal directions can be considered as "towards the goal". Do it in each direction and take the min. Sort of like what you are already doing in the 4-nieighbor case.

Comment: To clarify: By "periodic boundary conditions" do you mean that if an object moves off the top of the grid it reappears at the bottom and vice versa, and if it moves off the left of the grid it reappears at the right of the grid and vice versa? Also, the top and the bottom points in a given column `(i1, 0)` and `(i1, L-1)`, are distinct but one move away, rather than being identical points, but `(i1, 0)` and `(i1, L)` are identical points?

Comment: @RoryDaulton By periodic boundaries, effectively, I mean that the space has the shape of a torus, so top-bottom and left right are connected. As you say, I use `(L,L)=(0,0)`, and `(i1,0)` and `(i1, L-1)` are at distance 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find cyclic coordinate difference:

```
dx = Abs(x1 - x2)
if dx > L/2
   dx = L - dx
similar for dy
```

and distance in this case is known as Manhattan distance

```
dist = dx + dy
```

If diagonal move costs 1, then for 8-neighbour case solution is simple - to reach new position, one must perform maximum from dx and dy steps, but don't need more steps because moving along shorter direction is combined with moving along longer direction- diagonal moves.

```
dist = Max(dx, dy)
```

(also note that diagonal part is Min(dx, dy) and hor/vert part is Abs(dx - dy). Sum of these expressions is equal to maximum from dx, dy)

Comment: Excellent answer. You might mention (though it is obvious) the answer for the 4-neighbor case is simply `dx + dy`. Also, some explanation of how you arrive at the correct solution for the 8-neighbor case would be instructive; for instance: in the 8-neighbor case, an optimal solution takes you one square closer in both the `x` and `y` directions for every diagonal step, and one step closer in the more distance direction for every other step.

Comment: I find it useful to write this as dx = L/2 - Abs(Abs(x1 - x2) - L/2).